# How to set up Google Maps Utility Api in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-utils

I don't know why couldn't i figure it out. I am trying to add the [android_maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) library in the android studio.I have seen this [link](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) which was suggested by **google developers blog**.But i couldn't understand the way they suggested.
 **Can anyone give me step by step instruction to use android-maps-utils as library in Android Studio?? I have been stuck for two days. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: have you tried add dependency like this `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'` right? so it is not compiling or what?

Comment: can u give me step by step process from the first?? I have tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already fixed the *more than one package name* problem? If yes, omitted the followings.

I saw that in your "dependencies" element, you have `compile project(':library')` and `compile('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4')`. Is the `:library` the google maps utility library? If yes, then you add google maps utility dependency twice which leads to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

On that [link](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) with which suggested by google is everything how to include it. If you use Android Studio (as I saw in your `tags` to question):

add this line to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
}
```

and in the right nop corner you will see appears text `sync now`, so press it.
See attached picture.
[image]

And that's it, after in your classes you may use this library.

Comment: I am getting "Error:No such property: sonatypeUsername for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated" error after sync failed

Comment: @setubasak, please, post you `build.gradle` (the one inside folder `app`, not outside) file and file `gradle-wrapper.properties` inside folder `gradle`. At least we figured out what is the root of problem.

Comment: I have solved it .But i am getting this error now. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.maps.android'
You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0

Comment: According to what I found you have 2 libraries with same package name in your dependencies, but without viewing it I cannot say anything.

Comment: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile project(':library')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4')

Comment: it is possible, so if it said it will be enforced since version 1.0, so what version do you use now? I mean `build.gradle` if it is lower - need to update.

Comment: I have this gradle:1.0.0